# How many civilians died in Sabra and Shatila massacre?

Tags: middle-east, war-crime

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabra_and_Shatila_massacre) gives a wide range of between 460 and 3,500 civilians. Is this range still accepted by modern historians? maybe this is a better phrasing: **What parts of the disagreement still remains after all new evidence is accounted for?**

There is an abundance of sources but I don't have the skills needed to determine which are trustworthy, which are outdated (or use outdated evidence). in other words: for modern historians, that have had acess to and the ability/training to examine all new evidence, is there a non-fringe fraction that still believes that  460 (or 800, or 1390, 2000, 3500..) is plausible?

Comment: Casualty counts are notoriously difficult.  A quick web search offers, ". . .  [Sabra and Shatila: September 1982](https://www.amazon.com/Sabra-Shatila-Bayan-Nuwayhed-Al-Hout/dp/0745323022) (2004), which also appeared in an Arabic edition. Bayan provides the verified names of at least 1,390 victims, with estimates far exceeding that number of those who were detained and disappeared during the violence."  or [IMEU](https://imeu.org/article/the-sabra-shatila-massacre) which quotes the same 3,500 figure.

Comment: the Bayan link is dead (Page Not Found). yes, there is an abondance of sources but I don't have the skills needed to determine which are trustworthy, which are outdated (or use outdated evidence). in other words: for modern historians, that have had acess to and the ability/training to examine all new evidence, is there a non-fringe fraction that still believes that  460 (or 800, or 1390, 2000, 3500..) is plausible?

Comment: maybe this is a better phrasing: what parts of  the disagreement still remains after all new evidence is accounted for?

Comment: I found an alternate link.  I don't think anyone has the skills to reconcile the numbers. Every casualty count I've read, from every conflict in history, is disputed.  Frankly, I'd be more surprised by a narrow estimated range of casualties. BTW - in general, the question is weakened when the original poster replies in comments; please update the question so that it contains everything you know and everything you want to know.